# HTML Problems- Video Autoplay Playback Not working

Tags: html, video

I have started creating a website using HTML, however I want a video to play when I open the page and I have embedded the video as shown:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!-- GADGET SWAG WEBSITE -->
<html>

<head>
  <h1> Video HERE </h1>

<!-- Material Design -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <video width="1920" height="1080" autoplay>
  <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
</body>

</html>
```

This is an example video, however, it doesn't work on a local PC. I use Notepad++ to code in, but it doesn't seem to work?

Please help

thanks

yg.swagness

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
```

This code is the issue- it changes the way your page works and the video doesn't autoplay

Answer (score 0):

I tried it, and it worked try using a different editor I just used this basic one https://htmledit.squarefree.com